# $W^{2,2} \subset W^{1,p}$ for same $p > 2$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Consider the following problem:

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an bounded open set. Find conditions on $p$ for which $W^{2,2}(U) \subset W^{1,p}(U)$.

**What I have done**: I have proved that $W^{2,2}(U) \subset W^{1,p}(U)$ for all $p \in [1,2]$. This comes from the basic inclusion $L^{2}(U) \subset L^{p}(U)$ for $0 < p \leq 2$ (here I use that $U$ has finite Lebesgue measure). However I don't have any idea in what to do in case $p > 2$. Can one always construct a function which is in $W^{2,2}(U)$ but not in $W^{1,p}(U)$ for $p > 2$?

Comment: use Sobolev embedding theorem

Comment: But in my case, I dont have any regularity of $\partial U$. Can I say something in this case?

Comment: then you might want to look for counterexamples to the embedding $W^{1,2}$ into $L^p$ on non Lipschtiz domain

Comment: Exatly! It seems to be a little complicated.